# Linux console text editor - writing with colors

Tags: linux, colors, console

Is there a way to write a text in some console text editor under linux so that I can define the color of the text displayed based on system console colors defined (*color0.. *color15)?

For example I what the part of the text to be displayed as green, and part as cyan **while** I am typing in the text editor.

Comment: +1 For interest in any actual answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Txtfmt plugin for Vim provides what you're looking for. In addition to colors, you can also apply formatting to the text: e.g., bold, underline, italic, undercurl, etc..., as well as any combination thereof.

[Txtfmt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208)

Note: The errors mentioned by the previous poster are most likely caused by failure to enable filetype plugins in his vimrc. For some reason, the normally desired setting is not the default in many Vim installations. Adding the following line should prevent the errors:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Basic Syntax:

`echo '/033[` the color code `m'` (no spaces)

To reset

`echo '\033[0;0m'`

To make a literal color:

- In vi you can use `Ctrl-V` then `Esc` instead of `echo '\033`
- in nano you can use `Meta-V` then `Esc` instead of `echo '\033`

  - `Meta-v` can either be `Esc` then `v` or `Alt-v` depending on your setup.

Comment: I can't seems to understand how to use it. Let's assume that I use nano as text editor. So, what should I write to make next characters appear as cyan, for example?

Comment: still doesn't work. In nano, for example, I press alt+v, it says [verbatim input]. Them I write [0;0mblablabla and it just displays this characters with no color changes.

Comment: it should apply the color if you run `cat` on it

Comment: that's not exactly what I mean. I was looking for a way to see it as I type. Not later when I cat it, but live, as I type it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found so far is a VIM plugin called *TxtFmt* available at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208

The only problem is that I cannot make it work - On :MakeTextPage I get bunch of errors like "Unknown function: Txtfmt_GetTokStr" and many others.